# Are these synonyms: [code], [code-block], [code-formatting]?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, tag-synonyms

I came across a question today that was tagged with [code](/questions/tagged/code) which seemed an odd tag to have here on Meta.

Turned out that tag has 127 question and its description says:

> For questions or problems relating to the use of code in questions or answers on a site or the way that markdown works with code/preformatted text.

Queue its closest neighbors:

- [code-block](/questions/tagged/code-block) with 119 questions

  > is for questions about the block formatting used for code in posts.
- [code-formatting](/questions/tagged/code-formatting) with 642 questions

  > For questions about making code appear correctly in questions, answers and comments.

Hand checking some of its top questions show they all seem to be about the same topic and either of the  three tags can be applied to the questions.

16 question already have both [code](/questions/tagged/code) and [code-formatting](/questions/tagged/code-formatting)
10 questions have both [code](/questions/tagged/code) and [code-block](/questions/tagged/code-block)
18 questions have both [code-block](/questions/tagged/code-block) and [code-formatting](/questions/tagged/code-formatting)
3 question have all three tags

I propose we keep [code-formatting](/questions/tagged/code-formatting) as main tag and make [code-block](/questions/tagged/code-block) and [code](/questions/tagged/code) synonyms of that main tag.  For that purpose I already suggested a synonym [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested) but I lack the 5 reputation needed to suggest the synonym for [code-block](/questions/tagged/code-block).

If you agree with my analysis, please vote on (and/or create) the suggested synonyms. If you disagree write an answer with your compelling counter arguments or write a supportive answer so we can bribe a moderator to make those synonyms for us.

Comment: Should we add [tag:inline-code] into the mix as well?

Comment: @Luuklag I considered that but inline-code has a specific purpose in a specific context so I left it out for now. Feel free to write a poem to advocate for it to be added in the mix.

Comment: seeing that there are very few active users able to make these suggestions, perhaps you should reach out to a moderator, or one of those users directly via chat?

Comment: @Luuklag I'm not a fan of parading my own posts in chat to get them actioned. If someone feels to it I'm sure they will take steps, either in chat or by means of a flag. This is not a high-priority issue. Nothing burns down if it takes another 6 to 8 weeks to get resolved.  Thanks for the suggestion.